# Angular 2 - ngAfterContentChecked not being called for first time

Tags: angular, typescript, lifecycle

Searched everywhere but couldn't find. Working in Angular 2. Difficult to provide code sample as it is part of a large project so please pardon me for not providing a sample here. My question is regarding the life-cycle of Angular. This is a sample template for what I am trying to ask

```
<div >
     <div id='p' *ngFor="let item of data">
       {{item.employeeName}}
     </div>
</div>
```

In component class, I have a function which downloads the data from an external API. The API calls a success function whenever the data is pulled from the API. Following is the function called when successful:

```
public Success(data: any){ //returns array of type <T>
        this.data = data;
        console.log("success")
    }
```

In my component class I am trying to identify the life cycle events:

```
ngAfterContentChecked(){
    console.log('Content checked');
}
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    console.log('View checked');
}
```

I assume and understand, when I update the `this.data` collection, it should update my view because I am updating the underlying bound collection.

The first time it doesn't call the `ngAfterContentChecked` function after I update the `this.data` variable. Next time onwards, it is called just fine.

I have taken the point like delay in getting data into consideration already. Even if there is a delay in getting data, shouldn't `this.data = data` call the `ngAfterContentChecked` event? Well if it shouldn't, how come every request after the first one calls that event. Any help?